# PHP Socket Server - Is it safe to set verify_peer to false

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, tcp

I've been googling for a while to setup a TCP connection and every tutorial I noticed that in the context options the `verify_peer` is set to `false`.

I managed to make it work if I set the `verify_peer` to `false`, but then I set it to `true` it doesn't work. In production server I want to make it as secure as it can.

Is it safe to set `verify_peer` to `false` when creating a TCP socket server?

This is my the code to open a TCP connection.

```
function setupTcpStreamServer($pem_file, $pem_passphrase, $ip, $port) {
//setup and listen to a tcp IP/port, returning the socket stream

 //create a stream context for our SSL settings
 $context = stream_context_create();

 //Setup the SSL Options
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $pem_file);  // Our SSL Cert in PEM format
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pem_passphrase); // Private key Password
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
 stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

 //create a stream socket on IP:Port
 $socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://{$ip}:{$port}", $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context);
 stream_socket_enable_crypto($socket, false);

 return $socket;
}
```

Comment: include cafile too : For example, `stream_context_set_option($context, "ssl", "cafile", $conf[$_SESSION["agent"]]["cacert"]);` Note: cafile is the Certificate Authority file on local filesystem which should be used with the verify_peer context option to authenticate the identity of the remote peer

Comment: @KenLee is `cafile` the same as `local_cert`?

Comment: please see this https://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

Comment: Usually only servers have certificates, clients don't. So there's no point in the server trying to verify the client.

Comment: @aceraven777, you may also refer to this one sample script https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/-/stream_context_set_option/php-stream_context_set_option-function-examples.html (verify_peer=true)

Comment: Barmar is right, normally if you connect a client with a server then you should not bother on authenticating the identity of the remote peer, but I assume that you are connecting two servers , am I right ?

Comment: @KenLee @Barmar Well I am connecting to the TCP in the client side's browser. so server to client. So does this mean `verify_peer` here should be false?